# SendGrid Delivery Metrics

Tags: sendgrid

I've been scouring the SendGrid API [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/index.html), and I'm somewhat floored that there isn't an endpoint I can call, with a single user email address, that would return the same stats payload that the Email Activity web form does when searching for a single user.

I understand that Email Activity data will only go back 1 week, but that would be more than sufficent for my uses in this scenario.

Have I just missed something, or is there literally no way of retrieving this data from the API for a single user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, right now those endpoints don't exist. You'd need to implement the Event Webhook to get that data, which I know is not ideal. These endpoints are coming very soon though.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response... that's what I figured. Curious though, it looks like I could still accomplish this if I was able to construct this URL with the mail address I'm looking for in the POST data : https://sendgrid.com/logs/getData?_csrf_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - Is there something I can hit to generate that _csrf_token?

Answer (score 0):

These endpoints and analytics do not exist, but you can use a templating service on top of SendGrid to get detailed analytics by email address and/or template, via UI and API.

Check out sendwithus in particular, or even customer.io.